# Missing HTTP client dependencies for spring-cloud-starter-ribbon

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a simple Spring Boot application which has a simple REST client, that looks something like this:

```
@Service
public class MyRestClient {

  private static final String url = "http://localhost:8080/";

  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Autowired
  public MyRestClient(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
  }

  public String invoke() {
    return restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
  }
}
```

This works perfectly with Spring Boot.

Now I am trying to add `Spring Cloud` to the project to have Ribbon Client loadbalancing. I followed the links here:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/client-side-load-balancing/

or this here, which seems to be copy and paste but with more updated dependencies:

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-rest-client-with-netflix-ribbon

Even without adding any annotations to `MyRestClient`, the moment I add the following:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
<version>1.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I get the following exception:

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Factory method 'restTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClients
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        ... 31 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClients
        at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.<init>(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.java:88) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiate(BeanUtils.java:77) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder.detectRequestFactory(RestTemplateBuilder.java:596) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder.configureRequestFactory(RestTemplateBuilder.java:559) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder.configure(RestTemplateBuilder.java:527) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder.build(RestTemplateBuilder.java:515) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder.build(RestTemplateBuilder.java:501) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
```

Why is my REST client working without this dependency, but then without adding any annotations or anything, the moment I add this dependency, I get this exception?

I tried to add various dependencies from the documentation or examples here and there, like `spring-cloud-dependencies` (which seem deprecated), `spring-cloud-netflix` etc. to no avail.

What is the right dependency to add to get this to work?

Comment: Please post your `pom.xml`. Spring Cloud has release trains that are released inline with Spring Boot.

Comment: Please post your `application.yml`.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe If you could explain what could be the problem related to release trains (they can be quite confusing especially when you can't use the Spring parent pom because you have your own). It might be beneficial for people trying to solve similar problems. Thanks.

Comment: Release Trains are versioned inline with Spring Boot. E.g. `Dalston` is expecting Spring boot `1.5.x`, `Camden` is expecting `1.4.X`, `Brixton` is expecting `1.3.X`. Mixing spring cloud versions with unexpected Spring Boot versions can lead to runtime issues like you have detailed, unless a separate dependency is providing the `HttpClients`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the problem in [this forum post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/social/747740-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-http-impl-client-httpclients) and the dependency you need for `HttpClients` is [org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient) with version at least `4.3.3`.

Comment: Yes that was it. For some reason the version ribbon-httpclient was including was httpclient-4.2.1! I added a dependency to it explicitly using the latest 4.5.3 and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes add org.apache.httpcomponents in your pom.xml

Answer (score 4):

Your ribbon dependency manages the following artifact up to version 4.5.3 via `ribbon-httpclient 2.2.2`

```
<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
<artifactId>httpcomponents-client</artifactId>
<version>4.5.3</version>
```

I suggest to add explicit dependency for `httpcomponents-client` and excludes it from all others.

In other words try to add it in compile. not runtime:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```